# Where do I ask about finding an open source "shopping cart"?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm sorry. I don't know where to ask my question. Which site is the correct one for this:

> I am looking for an open source shopping cart that allows multiple
>   items in a kit or bundle.
>
> For example, if someone bought a pack of spices it would show the
>   various spices in the pack. Or, if I bought a barebones PC, it would
>   list the individual parts as part of the kit or bundle.
>
> I only saw ubercart for drupal. I have looked at all the rest. I did
>   find an older mod for oscommerce. Other and that I can't find
>   anything. Thanks for help.
>
> I prefer php, if that helps.

I posted it on Web Applications but it got closed.

Comment: I think this question would be on topic for [so] if you narrow it down to a specific problem you are having with code you've already written. As it stands, it's quite generic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's off-topic everywhere.

See [QA is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: do you have an alternative suggestion where would be good to ask this?

Comment: You might try here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters